# Как сделать pull только для текущего репозитория, при использовании модулей

Tags: git, git-pull

Есть у меня репозиторий с подмодулями (submodules) из других репозиториев. Когда я делаю `git pull origin master`, то автоматически приходят все изменения для текущего репозитория и его подмодулей. Какой командой можно получить изменения только для текущего репозитория?

Comment: согласно [документации](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#Working-on-a-Project-with-Submodules) по умолчанию под-модули не опрашиваются. видимо, вы переконфигурировали где-то что-то (например, [так](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4611512/4827341)), и теперь хотите «вернуть всё назад».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, это книга а не документация, что-то я не нашел описание по умолчанию в документации.

Answer (score 4):

По умолчанию git [не опрашивает](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8a36cd87b7c85a651ab388d403629865ffa3ba0d/builtin/fetch.c#L1332)(`recurse_submodules_default` ноль, по умолчанию) репозитории подмодулей, значит у Вас что-то выставлено в конфигурационных файлах, что заставляет git это делать. 
 Но подобное поведение можно явно отключить, вызвав pull таким образом:

```
git pull --no-recurse-submodules
```

Это явный запрет на получение(fetch) commit'ов для подмодулей.